# How to use batch file to do X if it's ran on a laptop?

Tags: installation, batch, script, unattended

How do I write a batch file to do different things based on whether it is ran on a desktop vs. laptop?  E.g. if on desktop, install x.  If on laptop, skip x and install y instead.

Edit: Windows 7 64-bit Pro. in a domain infrastructure setting.

I'm trying to write a batch file to be included in my unattend.xml using synchronous commands. The batch file ideally would detect whether the machine is a desktop system, and proceed to install the LANDESK agent designed for desktops, or if the machine is a laptop -- proceed to install the laptop flavor of the LANDESK agent.

Comment: On which OS? Also, please read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/267029) and make sure you're asking for the right thing. It's quite a strange request and maybe there's a better solution for the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.; updated question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you can do this with a Batch script.

If you use something like PowerShell, there are a bunch of options, but none of them are completely reliable.  For example, there are WMI classes for both [system enclosure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [battery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There's a [Technet blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/05/15/hey-scripting-guy-weekend-scripter-how-can-i-use-wmi-to-detect-laptops.aspx) that shows how to use both of these:

```
Function Get-Laptop
{
 Param(
 [string]$computer = "localhost"
 )
 $isLaptop = $false
 if(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_systemenclosure -ComputerName $computer |
    Where-Object { $_.chassistypes -eq 9 -or $_.chassistypes -eq 10 `
    -or $_.chassistypes -eq 14})
   { $isLaptop = $true }
 if(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_battery -ComputerName $computer)
   { $isLaptop = $true }
 $isLaptop
} # end function Get-Laptop

# *** entry point to script ***

If(get-Laptop) { "it's a laptop" }
else { "it's not a laptop"}
```